# How to request a route outside of MaterialApp in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I made a navbar widget and a MaterialApp inside a Row widget and I want access MaterialApp routes from the navbar. the problem is Navbar context has no idea about MaterialApp Routes. Any idea how can I achieve this?!

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: NavBar(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: MaterialApp(
              onGenerateRoute: routes,
            ),
          ),
        ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Why Would you have two MaterialApp?

Comment: one for access to navigator context, from navbar widget ,which is perment in page, and another one for routing page. Correct me if im wrong.